# continuity of two variable function using polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$f(x,y)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^3+y^3 \over x-y & \mbox{if } x \neq y \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x=y 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

how to dis-prove its continuity by using polar coordinates substitution.
and if it's not possible using polar coordinates substitution what would be its reason.

Comment: *"But I don't think that substitution should work."* Have you tried? Takes two seconds to check it does work. *" since, x tends to y should put condition on x."* What is this supposed to mean? Note that to disprove continuity, you are looking at the limit of $f$ along *one* path that tends to the origin. If this limit depends on the path, the function is discontinuous.

Comment: thanks, i understand the mistake. But still i am not able to disprove it using polar coordinates.

Comment: Do you have a reason to use polar coordinates? Here it won't be simple. Often, to disprove continuity at a point, it's enough to consider the limit along rays, i.e. the substitution $y=tx$. It works in polar coordinates as well, since it means the angle $\theta$ is constant. Here however, with $y=tx$ you will find the limit is always $0$. Hence it's not enough to disprove continuity (but of course it doesn't prove either that the function is continuous): you have to consider a curve that is not a straight line. It's possible to write this curve in polar coordinates, but it's not as simple.

Comment: No reason in particular, just out of curiosity.